# Testing Material-UI with jest is slow

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs, material-ui

I use reactjs and material-ui for my application. For unit testing I use jest.

Versions:

```
react: 0.13.3
material-ui: 0.12.1
jest-cli: 0.5.8
```

If I use a material-ui in a React.Component my jest test is really slow.

Example 1:

```
var React    = require('react');

module.exports = React.createClass({

    render: function () {
        return (<div></div>);
    }

});
```

Test takes **0.5 seconds**.

Example 2:

```
var React    = require('react');
var Material = require('material-ui');

module.exports = React.createClass({

    render: function () {
        return (<div></div>);
    }

});
```

Test takes **25 seconds**.

What I have tried/experienced so far:

- It doesn't make a difference if I turn mocking off/on for
  material-ui.
- It doesn't matter if I use a material-ui component or    not. Requiring seems to be the bottleneck.
- If have used two different preprocessors: react-tools, babel-jest

Does anyone have the same problem? **Or better a solution?**

Comment: Have you tried pulling in just the components you're using in `material-ui`? e.g. `require('material-ui/lib/card');`

Comment: I like the idea. I have used a similar approach. I started mocking the material-ui component which I used in my own component.

`jest.setMock('material-ui', {
TextField: <MOCK>
})`

Answer (score 0):

Use Karma & Jasmine.

We had the same issue with Jest being slow in general, so we ended up switching to Karma/Jasmine.  I think the Facebook team have been a bit quiet with Jest so I'm not so sure on its future.

Comment: We have the same problem. Simple tests take up to 2 seconds. I like the mocking concept though. Is there a good mocking library for jasmine/karma? I only now rewire and I am not a fan of it, it's rather time-consuming to mock all dependencies.

Comment: I think jasmine should be good enough - you can spy on functions and either call through to the actual code, call a fake mock function or just do nothing.